# How to enable Weblogic 12.1.2 JPA 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, weblogic, application-server

I have been deploying our web application to Weblogic server. However, although I was able to deploy the application successfully in this new version, the app does not start up and users cannot login. The log is:

```html
May 29, 2015 4:38:47 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
```

I believe this happens because Weblogic enables JPA 2.0 by default (but I am not sure of it). Is there a way to enable JPA 2.1?

PS: We are using hibernate 4.3.8 and I am not an expert on application servers.

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can upgrade to 12.1.3 then JPA 2.1 support is included but disabled by default, you can follow [their instructions for enabling it](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/EJBAD/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1508).  It amounts to putting the right jars on the classpath which you can do by adding this to the top of common/bin/commEnv.sh

```
PRE_CLASSPATH=$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/javax.persistence_2.1.jar:$MW_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
export PRE_CLASSPATH
```